# How to exclude the test folder from the test suite in testNG.xml file

Tags: testing, testng

I have a TestNG.xml file which contains one suite with name "newSuite" and this suite contains two test folders with name "abc" and "xyz" respectively. These two test folders contains different classes. Now, I want to exclude test folder with name "abc" without physically removing the test folder "abc" from the file or commenting it. Please help how do I achieve this objective.

My try:  tag is not working at test folder level.

TestNg.xml

```
<suite name="newSuite">
   <test thread-count="5" name="abc">  <!-- test folder abc -->
     <classes>
       <class name="testabc.day2" />
       <class name="testabc.day3" />
    </classes>
  </test>

   <test thread-count="5" name="xyz">  <!-- test folder xyz-->
     <classes>
       <class name="testabc.day1" />
       <class name="testabc.day4" />
     </classes>
   </test> 
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG lets you ignore all the @Test methods :

1. In a class (or)
2. In a particular package (or)
3. In a package and all of its child packages

using the new annotation **@Ignore.**
When used at the method level @Ignore annotation is functionally equivalent to @Test(enabled=false). Here's a sample that shows how to ignore all tests within a class.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Ignore;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Ignore
public class TestcaseSample {

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
    }
}
```

The @Ignore annotation has a higher priority than individual @Test method annotations. When @Ignore is placed on a class, all the tests in that class will be disabled.

For more reference you can follow this like : 
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Let me know if you have any more concerns.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i know about ignore annotation. I don't want to add or remove any annotation in class. I have only xml file through which I have to handle the execution.